# Audit failed but why?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

OK, so I was looking at this posting (https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9926862), and clicked on `Looks OK` and suddenly get a failed Audit warning. And even after reading it several times, I sure don't see why.

[image]

Escpecially considering that the Audit claims that this answer is

```
... abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. Please delete or recommend deletion when reviewing such posts.
```

As far as I can see, the answer posts exactly what the reader was asking for, so I don't see the problem here. I also don't see anything abusive or repulsive and even when I follow the link, it doesn't point to some weird site. Just some programming related stuff as well.

Comment: Did you notice the name of the author of the blog post in the link?

Answer (score 2):

> even when I follow the link, it doesn't point to some weird site. Just some programming related stuff as well.

Just because of that link, this answer was marked and deleted as spam. Even though the site is programming related but it is an irrelevant link to the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been better to remove the link then? After all the answer itself seems sensible to me. I could even have understood if the question itself were closed, because it is mostly a "gimme the code for my problem" type question, but that is a problem of the question and not the answer.

Comment: Even without the link, it would be a code-only answer. Though not a spam anymore but still a low-quality answer. A good quality answer should accompany some relevant details and explanation. I believe the intention was not to post an answer but to promote the blog.